# What contract options do I have for investing in a friend?

Tags: contract-law, finance

My friend is a bitcoin trader and makes a living doing it. I've seen his setup and trust him and I want to ensure if anything goes wrong that he'll make efforts to pay me back.

I know this is an investment of some kind. I own an LLC and want to invest some of the company money in his trading and let him keep a % of the profit too.

What legally binding contract options am I looking for exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I want to ensure **if anything goes wrong** that he'll make efforts to pay me back."

That would be a loan. An investment is where he pays you back if everything goes **right**. For that reason, investments are riskier and pay more *if* they pay out.